# Как правильно использовать asyncgur в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, fileupload

Пытаюсь загрузить на фотохостинг картинку с компьютера, но при её передаче возникает ошибка:

```
Возникло исключение: TypeError
Can not serialize value type: <class 'NoneType'>
 headers: {}
 value: None
```

Код который использую:

```
from asyncgur import Imgur
from os import getcwd
import asyncio

client_id = 'your client id'
imgur_app = Imgur(client_id)

async def main():
    f = open(getcwd() + '\\' + '434312.jpg', 'rb')
    image, response = await imgur_app.upload_image(image=f.read()) # тут ошибка
    assert response.success == True and response.status == 200
    print(image)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Ссылка на библиотеку, которую пытаюсь использовать - https://pypi.org/project/asyncgur/
В документации написано, что можно передать ссылку либо байты фотографии, с ссылкой работает всё на отлично, но с байтами - нет.

Полная ошибка:

```
Возникло исключение: TypeError
Can not serialize value type: <class 'NoneType'>
 headers: {}
 value: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "C:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\upp.py", line 10, in main
    image, response = await imgur_app.upload_image(image=f.read())
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\upp.py", line 15, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Покажите полный стек ошибки. Если код соответствует API библиотеки, то имеет смысл еще в issues библиотеки посмотреть ошибку или создать ее. Кст, `getcwd` не нужен, без него путь будет относительный от текущей рабочей директории, которую и так возвращает `getcwd`, поэтому достаточно так: `f = open('434312.jpg', 'rb')`. Но я бы рекомендовал использовать `pathlib` с получением папки приложения, где скрипт, чтобы не зависеть от рабочей директории

Comment: @gil9red обновил

Comment: Это всё ещё не похоже на полный стек ошибки

Comment: @andreymal это полная ошибка

Comment: @MaximChyorny значит у вас сломанный компьютер, потому что полная ошибка не может выглядеть так

Comment: Ну а вообще это выглядит как баг asyncgur, потому что пытаться запихнуть None-значения в formdata довольно глупо

Comment: Может имеются ввиду байты изображения? а не байты самого файла?

Comment: Допустим image_bytes = PIL.Image.open().tobytes()

Comment: @Александр ```Возникло исключение: AttributeError
module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'```

Comment: @Александр если написать `from PIL import Image` будет та же ошибка, которая написана в моем вопросе

Comment: PIL у меня это Python Image Library а у вас?

Comment: @Александр https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ PYPI

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130354/discussion-between--and-maxim-chyorny).